# How to share application link via message share application

Tags: android

For my application, I would like to give share option.

For this, I have edit text to give phone number and a share button. If user gives a valid number and clicks share button, list of all available message sending application should list. If user selects an application from the list then a message with the application link should send his phone using the selected application.

How can I implement this? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message link");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Chooser title text"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code,This is exactly that you want ,

```
       Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Your_EditText_object.getText().toString());
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Your Title"));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"your application link"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

References link:
https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void callShare(Context theCtx, String theImagePath, String theText) 
    {
        // Pass the message and Image path that you want to share
                File myImageFile = new File(theImagePath);
        String shareBody = theText;  //"Here is the share content body " ;
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        if (myImageFile.exists()) {
            // email address is required to be filled.
                        sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            // "file://" and .getAbsolutePath is very important for Extra_Stream.
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + myImageFile.getAbsolutePath()));
        } else if (!theText.isEmpty()) {
            sharingIntent.setType("text/*");
        }
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, ""); //"Subject here"
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        theCtx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
    }
```